# Why is non-blocking socket connect so slow?

Tags: c, sockets

when I do 100 non-block socket connection in 1 thread,it is very slow(the number of connection increased one by one),but if I do a blocking socket connection in 100 parallel threads(one connect per thread), it is very fast(get done immediately )

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK)!=0)
{
 perror("fcntl nonblock");
 return -1;
}

if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,&reuseAddr, sizeof(reuseAddr))!=0)
{
  perror("reuse addr");
  return -1;
}

sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SRV_ADDR);
sAddr.sin_port = htons(1972);

if ((n=connect(sock, (const struct sockaddr *) &sAddr, sizeof(sAddr))) < 0) 
{
  if (errno !=EINPROGRESS) {
      perror("client connect error");
      return -1;
  }     
}
else if (n>=0)
{
  printf("#%d connected\n",sock);
}

return sock;
```

Comment: I see a question in the title

Comment: @yi_H: the original title did not contain any question, it was edited later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Awesome question :-). Here's why I think this is happening. The standard says this:

> If the connection cannot be established **immediately** and O_NONBLOCK is
>   set for the file descriptor for the socket, connect() shall fail and
>   set errno to [EINPROGRESS]

The question of course is **what "immediately" means**. I believe that "immediately" is actually some small time that allows the `SYN`, `SYN-ACK`, `ACK` to happen. If it didn't wait at all, it would have 0-chance of actually succeeding.

So basically:

- The client sends a `SYN`
- **Waits** (blocks) for a small period of time ("immediately") for a `SYN-ACK`.
- Completes the connection

In doing so it returns successfully instead of `EADDRINUSE`.

Now, when using threads, each thread does this so nobody waits. They all just `connect(2)` and context switching allows everybody to do it almost simultaneously.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it waits for SYN-ACK, but this seems pretty much blocking behaviour to me. That acknowledge packet could be dropped by a router and then a re-send will happen with a timeout. that's a looong time. Actually that's relatively easy to test, I will do it when I'm in the office :)

Comment: @yi_H It's `blocking` alright, but for a short period of time :-). It doesn't wait for all the retransmits and whatnot; it gives TCP a chance to complete the connection.

Comment: looks I have to capture the packets to find the reasons. however, can it be explained that the stack/socket implementation,sending syn-packet one by one, always slower than sending multi syn-packet in different threads?

Comment: @jon Sending is not the problem (it's _very_ fast). The problem is the small waring time after the send (to give the server a chance to respond).